# Postgres: BEFORE UPDATE trigger

Tags: partitioning, postgresql-9.3

**Description**

In our environment (Postgres 9.3) we use extensive partitioning on dates. Additionally we use redirects to redirect `INSERT`s in the 'main' table to the corresponding child table (so due note that there actually is no data in the main table, all the data is in the child tables.

**Problem**

One of the processes is executing an `UPDATE` on the main table, but how could I redirect one of these `UPDATE`s to the correct child table?

So for instance if I say something simple as:

```
UPDATE transactions SET text = 'new text' WHERE id = 1 AND date = 201601;
```

That I redirect this `UPDATE` to the `transactions_201601` partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is not common practice to redirect your `UPDATE` queries to the correct table.

By ensuring that the `INDEX`es are setup in a correct way you make sure that the `UPDATE` is executed on the right partition table. So all in all setting up correct indexes is the solution.